# Failiure to update Windows defender virus & spyware definition - 0x8024402c

Tags: windows-update, anti-virus, windows-defender

An error with **error code 0x8024402c** is thrown  each time while trying to update *Windows Defender*'s virus & spyware definition.

Checked the following for diagnosis, and found no problem with these;

1. No pending important updates in *Windows Update* (automatic update option is checked)
2. No other antivirus installed
3. *Windows Update Agent* is up to date
4. No proxy server involved

What else do I have to check?

---

**UPDATE**

If the chosen answer below doesn't work for you, here's another solution that may work; change your DNS server IP to Google's, see how to do that [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).

Comment: Can you `ping fe2.update.microsoft.com` successfully?

Comment: Getting reply successfully on pinging `www.fe2.update.microsoft.com`

Comment: See my answer. Go to the link and click the "Run now" button for Windows 8.1.

Comment: @DavidPostill okay will do that and get back to you asap

Comment: Run windows update from control panel, what error if any do you get?

Comment: My ping requests to fe2.update.microsoft.com time out, must be a microsoft issue.

Comment: @Moab, okay. I'm seeing one available update in *Windows Update* now `Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3000850)`, I'll update it and let you know

Comment: @Moab You're not able to ping `www.fe2.update.microsoft.com` successfully ? For me it's working every time

Comment: might be a regional problem, Im in Texas.

Comment: Microsoft Security Essentials is reporting error 0x8024402F when updating my definitions. Not a problem we can solve. Have a great day.

Comment: @Moab, chat didn't work for me either. My *Windows Update* is still running, will take some time to see any error. Thanks for helping out

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzZaRVqKHfo)?

Comment: @Davidenko, that one is for when a proxy server is involved. I'm not using any in mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Windows defender virus & spyware definition not updating

Run the Microsoft "Fixit" application.

> When you use the Windows Update website or the Microsoft Update website to check for and install updates, you may receive one of the errors that are listed in the "Symptoms" section.
>
> **Windows 8.1, Windows 8 or Windows 7**
>
> The Automatically diagnose and fix common problems with Windows Update
>   troubleshooter may automatically fix the problem described in this
>   article.

There is a link on the page to Microsoft Fixit - the `run now` button

> ...
>
> **Symptoms**
>
> When you use the Windows Update website or the Microsoft Update
>   website to check for and install updates, you may receive one of the
>   following error code in the error messages:
>
> ...
>
> `0x8024402C              -2145107924  WU_E_PT_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`
>
> ...
>
> **Cause**
>
> These errors may be caused by any of the following issues:
>
> - Programs or processes that interfere with Internet communications
> - Resource issues on the computer
> - High Internet activity
> - Recoverable database errors

Source [Temporary connection-related errors may occur when you use Windows Update or Microsoft Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/836941)

---

#### Additional troubleshooting steps

If the above doesn't fix your issue, then see [How to solve connection problems concerning Windows Update or Microsoft Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818018).

Comment: David, [post this link also](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818018)

Comment: @Moab. Thanks, didn't know about this one. Answer updated.

Comment: @DavidPostill, It worked the first time after running fixit. Although when I try updating again, it shows the same error

Comment: @rps Try the other troubleshooting steps in the other link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818018

Comment: Tried that, didn't work 'm afraid. Right now, even after running *Fixit* it's not working. The *Fixit* although keeps fixing the issue `Windows Update error 0x80070057` every time I run it.

Comment: Well, thanks for your input, I'll mark it as answer. Will check for any corrupted system files that can be the root of the issue (The connectivity seems to be fine though) and If I find anything I'll let you know.

Comment: @rps Thanks. Sorry we couldn't "fix it" permanently for you ;)

Comment: :) Nah atleast it ran once, thanks to you. hopefully Windows 10 will fix it.